# Getting record data into class in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I guess I must be dense, I'm new to Delphi and am trying to read a sql result into a class to access it easily.
 I have created a dummy class to test like this:

```
type
test_class = class
 id:integer;
 job_number:string;
 cust_name :string ;
 procedure get_record_data;
end;
```

Then I call the procedure like this:

```
procedure test_class.get_record_data;
begin
 test_class.Create;
 test_class.id := tform3.adoQuery1.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
 test_class.job_number := tform3.adoQuery1.FieldByName('job number').AsString;
 test_class.cust_name := tform3.adoQuery1.FieldByName('customer name').AsString;
end;
```

Then I test my result like this:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 showmessage('Id number is ' + inttostr(test_class.id));
end;
```

The showmessage line throws a compiler error that says Method Identifier Expected.

The lines that start with test_class.id:=, test_class.job_number:= and                        test_class.cust_name:= 
all give me the same Method Identifier Expected as well as a Missing Operator or semicolon error.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to go about this? Once I get this done, will null values present an issue?

Comment: I certainly won't use this as an answer, because it was written by me while I was still learning Delphi, and because this is a link to another website, but I wrote this a while back: http://tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7420

Comment: Also it doesn't directly solve your issue, but it's just an idea I was researching at one time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not use a class as an instance. You will have to keep a reference to the created instance, according your example it could look like this ...

```
type
Ttest_class=class
 id:integer;
 job_number:string;
 cust_name :string ;
 Class Function get_record_data(ADS:TCustomAdodataset):Ttest_class;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TC:Ttest_class;
begin
   TC := Ttest_class.get_record_data(AdoQuery1);
   try
   showmessage('Id number is ' + inttostr(TC.id));
   finally
     TC.Free
   end;
end;


class function Ttest_class.get_record_data(ADS: TCustomAdodataset): Ttest_class;
begin
 Result := Ttest_class.Create;
 Result.id:=ADS.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
 Result.job_number:= ADS.FieldByName('job number').AsString;
 Result.cust_name:= ADS.FieldByName('customer name').AsString;
end;
```

As suggested by @MarjanVenema and requested by comment a preferable version:

```
type
  Ttest_class = class
    id: integer;
    job_number: string;
    cust_name: string;
    Constructor Create(ADS: TCustomAdodataset);
  end;

Constructor Ttest_class.Create(ADS: TCustomAdodataset);
begin
  id := ADS.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
  job_number := ADS.FieldByName('job number').AsString;
  cust_name := ADS.FieldByName('customer name').AsString;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TC: Ttest_class;
begin
  TC := Ttest_class.Create(ADOQuery1);
  try
    showmessage('Id number is ' + inttostr(TC.id));
  finally
    TC.Free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That works perfectly and will get me up and going with a lot better understanding. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bummi For a beginning Delphi programmer, wouldn't it be better to show him to create an instance rather then use class functions?

Comment: @JanDoggen I agree, I was picking up his approach, trying to show how to avoid hard references within the class. Since the way you mentioned is already shown in eKek0 answer changing my answer should not be necessary.

Comment: Why a class function instead of simply a constructor taking the ado dataset as a parameter? The class function's name also doesn't convey the fact that the caller takes ownership of lifetime management of what is returned.

Comment: @MarjanVenema You're right, that would be actually the most obvious way.

Comment: I'm starting to get a better handle on calling instances instead of the hard reference to the class. I think I understand the lifetime management. If you create it, its there to use until you free it. If you close the app and don't free it, then it's a memory leak. Correct? Can you show me how to code the constructor? I really do want to learn this stuff.

Comment: I kept the original version  to retain the reference to the comments.
@user2662392  Correct.

Comment: bummi, Thank you very much. Now for what I hope is the final question on this subject, why do you call ADS as TCustomAdodataset instead of TAdoQuery?

Comment: TCustomAdodataset the base class for TADODataSet, TADOQuery, TADOTable and TADOStoredProc, this way you can use any of these components.

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 6):

`test_class` is a type and not an instance variable. To access an object of type `test_class` you need to declare a variable of that type, create an instance and, just then, use its fields, properties of methods. Finally, you need to free the memory of that object.

For example (to not confuse you I won't use a `try...finally`):

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tc: test_class;  //instance variable declaration
begin
  tc := test.class.Create; //creation of the object
  tc.get_record_data; //call a method to fill the class fields
  ShowMessage('Id number is ' + inttostr(tc.id)); //use of the object
  tc.Free; //freeing the memory object
end;
```

By the way, by convention the user defined types in Delphi begins with `T` and follows with camel case without underscores, as in `TTestClass` instead of `test_class`.

I guess that you don't know the concepts of classes, objects and instance variables. Google for their definitions, there is a lot of information about that, for example [this tutorial](http://delphi.about.com/od/course/a/oop_intro.htm).

---

In your `get_record_data method` if you want to fill the variables of the instance that they belongs, the thing will go like:

```
procedure test_class.get_record_data ;
begin
  id         := tform3.adoQuery1.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
  job_number := tform3.adoQuery1.FieldByName('job number').AsString;
  cust_name  := tform3.adoQuery1.FieldByName('customer name').AsString;
end;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. The Showmessage works, but the test_class.id:= and other lines that read the sql still don't work. Any suggestions for those lines?

Comment: Add a try finally and you'd get my vote. Call me weird but I like to see good practices being promoted.

Answer (score 1):

`Test_Class` needs to know what it is populating it's data from. You are trying to refer to `Form3.ADOQuery1`, but TForm3 will almost definitely be the Class, not an object.

If you're using Delphi auto-generated code then there should be a line saying something like

`var
Form3: TForm3`

at the top of your unit. If this is the case then you can correct your code by replacing all TForm3 with Form3 in that procedure.

A better solution is to give your `get_record_data` procedure the query it is to fill from:

```
procedure test_class.get_record_data (const aQuery: TADOQuery);
begin
  id         := aQuery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
  job_number := aQuery.FieldByName('job number').AsString;
  cust_name  := aQuery.FieldByName('customer name').AsString;
end;
```

Even better for such a small object is to pass in the 3 variables directly:

`procedure test_class.set_object_data(const aID: integer; const aJob_Number, aCust_Name: string`